# How do I remove the parameter hints tooltip in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[VS code tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wFR8.png)

How do I disable this floating hint/tooltip in VS Code? This happens with expressjs only.

My `editor.hover.enabled` is already set to false. I don't think any extensions I have installed are responsible for this.

- I have disabled and checked with IntelliSense extensions for JS, ESLint but still it's the same
- Disabled all hover settings in VS Code preferences

Comment: "_I don't think any extensions I have installed are responsible for this._" you can actually check by restarting with extensions disabled, and doing an [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false` in a [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson).